Azure DevopsPublish is publishing all git folders
When I publish my .Net project in VS only few and required folders are publishing, but while I publish from Azure devops pipiline. I am getting all the git code including csproj, sql files etc. There might be some configuration which I am missing, please let me know where to control the publish task
tried changing the publish path
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands: msbuild

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet '

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$/XXXXXXXPath.sln'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$/XXXXXXXPath.Web.csproj'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'
    arguments: '''--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'''
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    PublishSymbols: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files '
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()


Hi Manoj, please show us your pipeline definition.

steps:

task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'dotnet publish'
inputs:
command: publish
publishWebProjects: false
projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'
arguments: '''--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'''
modifyOutputPath: false

This is for Publish and now I am getting an error
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

@Manoj, Please post your YAML content and the failed logs on your above original comment.

You can configure your pipeline like as below,
# azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  buildConfiguration: Release

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: 'path/to/solution-name.sln'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'path/to/project-name.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'


The 'dotnet restore' step will restore the required NuGet packages.

The 'dotnet publish' step will do the following things:

Build the specified project (.csproj).
Archive the build artifact files (generated by build) and the resources/dependence files required by the project into a ZIP file.
The ZIP file will be put to the specified directory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)".


After the 'dotnet publish' step, you can use the related deploy task to deploy/publish the ZIP file from the directory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)".




Tried this Below is the error
steps: - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 displayName: 'dotnet publish' inputs: command: publish publishWebProjects: false projects: '$(Parameters.projects)' arguments: '''--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)''' modifyOutputPath: false This is for Publish and now I am getting an error ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

@Manoj, What is the type of your C# project? A web app or others? And how you build you project? Please provide the full YAML of your previous pipeline which publishes all the git files.

pool:
name: Azure Pipelines
demands: msbuild
steps:


task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
displayName: 'Use NuGet '


task: NuGetCommand@2
displayName: 'NuGet restore'
inputs:
restoreSolution: '$Project Path.sln'


task: MSBuild@1
displayName: 'Build solution'
inputs:
solution: '$/Project Path web.csproj'
msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"'


This is till build, I dont face any issue here

Issue

task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'dotnet publish'
inputs:
command: publish
publishWebProjects: false
projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'
arguments: '''--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'''
modifyOutputPath: false
task: CopyFiles@2
displayName: 'Copy Files '
inputs:
TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
CleanTargetFolder: true
OverWrite: true
task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
inputs:
PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'


@Manoj, Please add the information to above post of your question with the readable format. Do not post it in the comment.

updated in post

@Manoj, You can remove the MSBuild@1 and CopyFiles@2 from your pipeline, just like as the configurations set in my above sample.

error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.401\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.401\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

@Manoj, What is the TargetFramework of your project? Do you set your project to import any XML files when building?

What is the TargetFramework of your project? .net 4.5
Do you set your project to import any XML files when building? No
Can you let me know how to debug next?
